# How to extend epplus data extractor with method like WithAllProperties

Tags: c#, excel, generics, reflection, epplus

I am working with excel files. I have to read tabular values stored in excel sheets and deserialize them to objects. For this, I am using OfficeOpenXml with the help of EPPlus.DataExtractor. My Excel tables have several columns, thus my classes have several properties - with different datatypes strings, ints, DateTimes, doubles and nullable ints, DateTimes, doubles. I cannot assume that more types won't come in time. For example, a class for deserializing excel row can look like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Column("A")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Column("B")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Column("C")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Column("D")]
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
}
```

Column is my own attribute, which tells the extractor which column contains value for a given property:

```
public class ColumnAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public ColumnAttribute(string column) => Column = column;
}
```

Thats why, i can use the EPPlus like this

```
public class MyModelExtractor
{
    private readonly string _path;
    public MyModelExtractor(string path) => _path = path;

    public List<MyModel> Create()
    {
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(_path)))
        {
            var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            return worksheet
                .Extract<MyModel>()
                .WithProperty(p => p.Id, MyModel.GetColumnAnnotation(p => p.Id))
                .WithProperty(p => p.Code , MyModel.GetColumnAnnotation(p => p.Code ))
                .WithProperty(p => p.Number, MyModel.GetColumnAnnotation(p => p.Number))
                .WithProperty(p => p.ValidTo , MyModel.GetColumnAnnotation(p => p.ValidTo ))
                .GetData(2, row => worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value != null)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Now, there is something more in MyModel class, namely:

```
public static string GetColumnAnnotation<T>(Expression<Func<MyModel, T>> propertySelector) =>
        AttributeExtractor.GetPropertyAttributeValue<MyModel, T, ColumnAttribute, string>(propertySelector, attribute => attribute.Column);
```

which, as can be seen, is used in WithProperty method, to get the value of Column attribute (simply a string).

For completness, I will provide AttributeExtractor, which looks like this:

```
public static class AttributeExtractor
{
    public static TValue GetPropertyAttributeValue<T, TOut, TAttribute, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TOut>> propertyExpression,
        Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member;
        return propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() is TAttribute attr
            ? valueSelector(attr)
            : throw new MissingMemberException(typeof(T).Name + "." + propertyInfo.Name, typeof(TAttribute).Name);
    }
}
```

Now, in every model class (and I have tens of them) I have to provide this static method GetPropertyAttributeValue. What is more problematic, the classes contain lots of properties, so the call to WithProperty is done many times. And, again, for every class, I have separate corresponding extractor.

I thought about creating a generic version of Extractor, like

```
public class Extractor<T> { ... }
```

where T will be a type like MyModel, and then I could write some method, like WithAllProperties() which will replace all the calls to WithProperty.

The class would then look like this

```
public class Extractor<T> 
{
    ...ctor and _path, and then:
    public List<T> Create()
    {
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(_path)))
        {
            var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            return worksheet
                .Extract<T>()
                .WithAllProperties()
                .GetData(2, row => worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value != null)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am struggling with the WithAllProperties method. It should look like this:

```
public static ICollectionPropertyConfiguration<T> WithAllProperties<T>(
        this IDataExtractor<T> extractor) where T : class, new()
    {
       foreach(var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            extractor = extractor.WithProperty(/1/, /2/);

        return extractor as ICollectionPropertyConfiguration<T>;
    }
```

What is missing is /1/ which should of type

```
Expression<Func<T,TProperty>>
```

I cannot dynamically generate this value (without some tricks which seem not intelligent for me, like switching the type of property variable, and creating the needed Expression. It works, but when new types come, this switch has to be extended and I am sure it can be done dynamically using reflection). Another thing is /2/ which is a value of Column attribute for corresponding property - for this I have no idea how to obtain it.

Any help/hints/clues needed.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, since no one had time to provide any hints, I crafted my own solution. It is not ideal - maybe it can be improved, but I am satisfied with the results, since my code has reduced a lot.

First change was to clean all the excel models like MyModel from the static GetColumnAnnotation method. What left are pure properties with Column attribute. Next change was to get rid of the generic AttributeExtractor - it is not needed any more.

I created a generic ExcelExtractor class whic looks very slim:

```
public class ExcelExtractor<T> where T: class, new()
{
    public ExcelExtractor(IExcelPathProvider pathProvider) => _pathProvider = pathProvider;
    public List<T> Create(int sheetNumber)
    {
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(_pathProvider.GetPath())))
        {
            var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetNumber];
            return worksheet
                .Extract<T>()
                .WithAllProperties()
                .GetData(2, row => worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value != null)
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    private readonly IExcelPathProvider _pathProvider;
}
```

Next, I created some extension class which looks like this:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static ICollectionPropertyConfiguration<T> WithAllProperties<T>(
        this IDataExtractor<T> extractor) where T : class, new() =>
        typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        .Aggregate(extractor, ExtractProperty) as ICollectionPropertyConfiguration<T>;

    private static string ToColumn(this PropertyInfo property) =>
        ((ColumnAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true)
            .First()).Column;
    private static IDataExtractor<T> ExtractProperty<T>(IDataExtractor<T> extractor,
        PropertyInfo property) where T : class, new()
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            return extractor.WithProperty(ExpressionGenerator<T>.GetStringProperty(property), property.ToColumn());

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            return extractor.WithProperty(ExpressionGenerator<T>.GetIntProperty(property), property.ToColumn());

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
            return extractor.WithProperty(ExpressionGenerator<T>.GetNullableIntProperty(property), property.ToColumn());

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            return extractor.WithProperty(ExpressionGenerator<T>.GetDateTimeProperty(property), property.ToColumn());

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            return extractor.WithProperty(ExpressionGenerator<T>.GetNullableDateTimeProperty(property), property.ToColumn());

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            return extractor.WithProperty(ExpressionGenerator<T>.GetBooleanProperty(property), property.ToColumn());

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
            return extractor.WithProperty(ExpressionGenerator<T>.GetNullableBooleanProperty(property), property.ToColumn());

        throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown type {property.PropertyType}");
    }
    private static class ExpressionGenerator<T>
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, string>> GetStringProperty(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(GetMember(property), Parameter);
        public static Expression<Func<T, int>> GetIntProperty(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(GetMember(property), Parameter);
        public static Expression<Func<T, int?>> GetNullableIntProperty(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int?>>(GetMember(property), Parameter);
        public static Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> GetDateTimeProperty(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(GetMember(property), Parameter);
        public static Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> GetNullableDateTimeProperty(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime?>>(GetMember(property), Parameter);
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetBooleanProperty(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(GetMember(property), Parameter);
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool?>> GetNullableBooleanProperty(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool?>>(GetMember(property), Parameter);

        private static readonly ParameterExpression Parameter =
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        private static MemberExpression GetMember(PropertyInfo property) =>
            Expression.Property(Parameter, property.Name);

    }
}
```

Probably the solution can be improved even more, and I will be very grateful if someone provides any hints, but I am very satisfied with the results - I have a generic Extractor which works like a charm for any new excel models I can ever create. If some extra datatype is needed I will add two methods to my helper class.

Comment: Thank you for using the library. I've been considering extending it to support attributes, it's nice to know that it would be useful to other people.